# How to restart fabric containers (x86_64-1.1.0-preview) with data persistence to perform chaincode invoke functions normally?

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

I have set up data persistence in the peer and the couchdb containers and have run through the commands with the chaincode_example02 chaincode manually on both peers in the cli container (with the command line commented in docker-compose-cli.yaml).  The last things I did is to shutdown the containers and then restart them.  After the restart, I can query the "query" function of the chaincode without any problem and all the data are still there (balances of a and b) and the same as before I perform the shutdown.  However, I get the following error when I invoke the "invoke" function on both peer containers.

```
Error: Error sending transaction invoke: got unexpected status: NOT_FOUND -- channel does not exist
```

How to restart the fabric containers (x86_64-1.1.0-preview) with data persistence so that I can perform chaincode invoke functions normally after the restart?

Ubuntu version:

```
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 17.10
Release:    17.10
Codename:   artful
```

Hyperledger Fabric version:

```
x86_64-1.1.0-preview
```

All actions below are done with the "first-network" (byfn.sh) example:

Configuration Changes:

added the following lines in the volumes sections in docker-compose-base.yaml for peer container data persistence

```
for peer0.org1.example.com:
    - ../persist-data/peer0org1:/var/hyperledger/production
for peer1.org1.example.com:
    - ../persist-data/peer1org1:/var/hyperledger/production
for peer0.org2.example.com:
    - ../persist-data/peer0org2:/var/hyperledger/production
for peer1.org2.example.com:
    - ../persist-data/peer1org2:/var/hyperledger/production
```

added the following lines in the volumes sections in docker-compose-couch.yaml for couchdb container data persistence

```
for couchdb0:
    - ./persist-data/couchdb0:/opt/couchdb/data
for couchdb1:
    - ./persist-data/couchdb1:/opt/couchdb/data
for couchdb2:
    - ./persist-data/couchdb2:/opt/couchdb/data
for couchdb3:
    - ./persist-data/couchdb3:/opt/couchdb/data
```

I have also changed to couchdb port numbers as follow to avoid conflicts with the couchdb installed on my computer:

```
for couchdb0:
  - "6984:5984"
for couchdb1:
  - "7984:5984"
for couchdb2:
  - "8984:5984"
for couchdb3:
  - "9984:5984"
```

Actions and commands:

```
cd to the first-network directory
../../bin/cryptogen generate --config=./crypto-config.yaml
export FABRIC_CFG_PATH=$PWD
../../bin/configtxgen -profile TwoOrgsOrdererGenesis -outputBlock ./channel-artifacts/genesis.block
export CHANNEL_NAME=mychannel  && ../../bin/configtxgen -profile TwoOrgsChannel -outputCreateChannelTx ./channel-artifacts/channel.tx -channelID $CHANNEL_NAME
../../bin/configtxgen -profile TwoOrgsChannel -outputAnchorPeersUpdate ./channel-artifacts/Org1MSPanchors.tx -channelID $CHANNEL_NAME -asOrg Org1MSP
../../bin/configtxgen -profile TwoOrgsChannel -outputAnchorPeersUpdate ./channel-artifacts/Org2MSPanchors.tx -channelID $CHANNEL_NAME -asOrg Org2MSP
docker-compose -f docker-compose-cli.yaml -f docker-compose-couch.yaml up -d
CORE_PEER_MSPCONFIGPATH=/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/users/Admin@org1.example.com/msp
CORE_PEER_ADDRESS=peer0.org1.example.com:7051
CORE_PEER_LOCALMSPID="Org1MSP"
CORE_PEER_TLS_ROOTCERT_FILE=/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/peers/peer0.org1.example.com/tls/ca.crt

# enter the cli container and execute the commands in the cli container manually
docker exec -it cli bash
export CHANNEL_NAME=mychannel
peer channel create -o orderer.example.com:7050 -c $CHANNEL_NAME -f ./channel-artifacts/channel.tx --tls --cafile /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/ordererOrganizations/example.com/orderers/orderer.example.com/msp/tlscacerts/tlsca.example.com-cert.pem
peer channel join -b mychannel.block
CORE_PEER_MSPCONFIGPATH=/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/peerOrganizations/org2.example.com/users/Admin@org2.example.com/msp CORE_PEER_ADDRESS=peer0.org2.example.com:7051 CORE_PEER_LOCALMSPID="Org2MSP" CORE_PEER_TLS_ROOTCERT_FILE=/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/peerOrganizations/org2.example.com/peers/peer0.org2.example.com/tls/ca.crt peer channel join -b mychannel.block
peer channel update -o orderer.example.com:7050 -c $CHANNEL_NAME -f ./channel-artifacts/Org1MSPanchors.tx --tls --cafile /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/ordererOrganizations/example.com/orderers/orderer.example.com/msp/tlscacerts/tlsca.example.com-cert.pem
CORE_PEER_MSPCONFIGPATH=/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/peerOrganizations/org2.example.com/users/Admin@org2.example.com/msp CORE_PEER_ADDRESS=peer0.org2.example.com:7051 CORE_PEER_LOCALMSPID="Org2MSP" CORE_PEER_TLS_ROOTCERT_FILE=/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/peerOrganizations/org2.example.com/peers/peer0.org2.example.com/tls/ca.crt peer channel update -o orderer.example.com:7050 -c $CHANNEL_NAME -f ./channel-artifacts/Org2MSPanchors.tx --tls --cafile /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/ordererOrganizations/example.com/orderers/orderer.example.com/msp/tlscacerts/tlsca.example.com-cert.pem
peer chaincode install -n mycc -v 1.0 -p github.com/chaincode/chaincode_example02/go/
CORE_PEER_MSPCONFIGPATH=/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/peerOrganizations/org2.example.com/users/Admin@org2.example.com/msp CORE_PEER_ADDRESS=peer0.org2.example.com:7051 CORE_PEER_LOCALMSPID="Org2MSP" CORE_PEER_TLS_ROOTCERT_FILE=/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/peerOrganizations/org2.example.com/peers/peer0.org2.example.com/tls/ca.crt peer chaincode install -n mycc -v 1.0 -p github.com/chaincode/chaincode_example02/go/
peer chaincode instantiate -o orderer.example.com:7050 --tls --cafile /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/ordererOrganizations/example.com/orderers/orderer.example.com/msp/tlscacerts/tlsca.example.com-cert.pem -C $CHANNEL_NAME -n mycc -v 1.0 -c '{"Args":["init","a", "100", "b","200"]}' -P "OR ('Org1MSP.member','Org2MSP.member')"
peer chaincode query -C $CHANNEL_NAME -n mycc -c '{"Args":["query","a"]}'
peer chaincode query -C $CHANNEL_NAME -n mycc -c '{"Args":["query","b"]}'
peer chaincode invoke -o orderer.example.com:7050  --tls --cafile /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/ordererOrganizations/example.com/orderers/orderer.example.com/msp/tlscacerts/tlsca.example.com-cert.pem  -C $CHANNEL_NAME -n mycc -c '{"Args":["invoke","a","b","10"]}'
peer chaincode query -C $CHANNEL_NAME -n mycc -c '{"Args":["query","a"]}'
peer chaincode query -C $CHANNEL_NAME -n mycc -c '{"Args":["query","b"]}'

CORE_PEER_MSPCONFIGPATH=/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/peerOrganizations/org2.example.com/users/Admin@org2.example.com/msp CORE_PEER_ADDRESS=peer0.org2.example.com:7051 CORE_PEER_LOCALMSPID="Org2MSP" CORE_PEER_TLS_ROOTCERT_FILE=/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/peerOrganizations/org2.example.com/peers/peer0.org2.example.com/tls/ca.crt peer chaincode query -C $CHANNEL_NAME -n mycc -c '{"Args":["query","a"]}'
CORE_PEER_MSPCONFIGPATH=/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/peerOrganizations/org2.example.com/users/Admin@org2.example.com/msp CORE_PEER_ADDRESS=peer0.org2.example.com:7051 CORE_PEER_LOCALMSPID="Org2MSP" CORE_PEER_TLS_ROOTCERT_FILE=/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/peerOrganizations/org2.example.com/peers/peer0.org2.example.com/tls/ca.crt peer chaincode query -C $CHANNEL_NAME -n mycc -c '{"Args":["query","b"]}'
CORE_PEER_MSPCONFIGPATH=/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/peerOrganizations/org2.example.com/users/Admin@org2.example.com/msp CORE_PEER_ADDRESS=peer0.org2.example.com:7051 CORE_PEER_LOCALMSPID="Org2MSP" CORE_PEER_TLS_ROOTCERT_FILE=/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/peerOrganizations/org2.example.com/peers/peer0.org2.example.com/tls/ca.crt peer chaincode invoke -o orderer.example.com:7050  --tls --cafile /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/ordererOrganizations/example.com/orderers/orderer.example.com/msp/tlscacerts/tlsca.example.com-cert.pem  -C $CHANNEL_NAME -n mycc -c '{"Args":["invoke","a","b","5"]}'
CORE_PEER_MSPCONFIGPATH=/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/peerOrganizations/org2.example.com/users/Admin@org2.example.com/msp CORE_PEER_ADDRESS=peer0.org2.example.com:7051 CORE_PEER_LOCALMSPID="Org2MSP" CORE_PEER_TLS_ROOTCERT_FILE=/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/peerOrganizations/org2.example.com/peers/peer0.org2.example.com/tls/ca.crt peer chaincode query -C $CHANNEL_NAME -n mycc -c '{"Args":["query","a"]}'
CORE_PEER_MSPCONFIGPATH=/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/peerOrganizations/org2.example.com/users/Admin@org2.example.com/msp CORE_PEER_ADDRESS=peer0.org2.example.com:7051 CORE_PEER_LOCALMSPID="Org2MSP" CORE_PEER_TLS_ROOTCERT_FILE=/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/peerOrganizations/org2.example.com/peers/peer0.org2.example.com/tls/ca.crt peer chaincode query -C $CHANNEL_NAME -n mycc -c '{"Args":["query","b"]}'

peer chaincode query -C $CHANNEL_NAME -n mycc -c '{"Args":["query","a"]}'
peer chaincode query -C $CHANNEL_NAME -n mycc -c '{"Args":["query","b"]}'
exit

#get out of the cli container

docker-compose -f docker-compose-cli.yaml -f docker-compose-couch.yaml down

docker container ls
docker network ls

docker-compose -f docker-compose-cli.yaml -f docker-compose-couch.yaml up -d

docker container ls
docker network ls

CORE_PEER_MSPCONFIGPATH=/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/users/Admin@org1.example.com/msp
CORE_PEER_ADDRESS=peer0.org1.example.com:7051
CORE_PEER_LOCALMSPID="Org1MSP"
CORE_PEER_TLS_ROOTCERT_FILE=/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/peers/peer0.org1.example.com/tls/ca.crt

# enter the cli container and execute the commands in the cli container manually
docker exec -it cli bash
export CHANNEL_NAME=mychannel

peer chaincode query -C $CHANNEL_NAME -n mycc -c '{"Args":["query","a"]}'
peer chaincode query -C $CHANNEL_NAME -n mycc -c '{"Args":["query","b"]}'

CORE_PEER_MSPCONFIGPATH=/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/peerOrganizations/org2.example.com/users/Admin@org2.example.com/msp CORE_PEER_ADDRESS=peer0.org2.example.com:7051 CORE_PEER_LOCALMSPID="Org2MSP" CORE_PEER_TLS_ROOTCERT_FILE=/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/peerOrganizations/org2.example.com/peers/peer0.org2.example.com/tls/ca.crt peer chaincode query -C $CHANNEL_NAME -n mycc -c '{"Args":["query","a"]}'
CORE_PEER_MSPCONFIGPATH=/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/peerOrganizations/org2.example.com/users/Admin@org2.example.com/msp CORE_PEER_ADDRESS=peer0.org2.example.com:7051 CORE_PEER_LOCALMSPID="Org2MSP" CORE_PEER_TLS_ROOTCERT_FILE=/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/peerOrganizations/org2.example.com/peers/peer0.org2.example.com/tls/ca.crt peer chaincode query -C $CHANNEL_NAME -n mycc -c '{"Args":["query","b"]}'

# get error in the next two commands invoking the "invoke" function in the chaincode. The full error text is at the bottom.

peer chaincode invoke -o orderer.example.com:7050  --tls --cafile /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/ordererOrganizations/example.com/orderers/orderer.example.com/msp/tlscacerts/tlsca.example.com-cert.pem  -C $CHANNEL_NAME -n mycc -c '{"Args":["invoke","b","a","10"]}'

CORE_PEER_MSPCONFIGPATH=/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/peerOrganizations/org2.example.com/users/Admin@org2.example.com/msp CORE_PEER_ADDRESS=peer0.org2.example.com:7051 CORE_PEER_LOCALMSPID="Org2MSP" CORE_PEER_TLS_ROOTCERT_FILE=/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/peerOrganizations/org2.example.com/peers/peer0.org2.example.com/tls/ca.crt peer chaincode invoke -o orderer.example.com:7050  --tls --cafile /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/ordererOrganizations/example.com/orderers/orderer.example.com/msp/tlscacerts/tlsca.example.com-cert.pem  -C $CHANNEL_NAME -n mycc -c '{"Args":["invoke","b","a","5"]}'

peer chaincode query -C $CHANNEL_NAME -n mycc -c '{"Args":["query","a"]}'
peer chaincode query -C $CHANNEL_NAME -n mycc -c '{"Args":["query","b"]}'

CORE_PEER_MSPCONFIGPATH=/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/peerOrganizations/org2.example.com/users/Admin@org2.example.com/msp CORE_PEER_ADDRESS=peer0.org2.example.com:7051 CORE_PEER_LOCALMSPID="Org2MSP" CORE_PEER_TLS_ROOTCERT_FILE=/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/peerOrganizations/org2.example.com/peers/peer0.org2.example.com/tls/ca.crt peer chaincode query -C $CHANNEL_NAME -n mycc -c '{"Args":["query","a"]}'
CORE_PEER_MSPCONFIGPATH=/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/peerOrganizations/org2.example.com/users/Admin@org2.example.com/msp CORE_PEER_ADDRESS=peer0.org2.example.com:7051 CORE_PEER_LOCALMSPID="Org2MSP" CORE_PEER_TLS_ROOTCERT_FILE=/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/peerOrganizations/org2.example.com/peers/peer0.org2.example.com/tls/ca.crt peer chaincode query -C $CHANNEL_NAME -n mycc -c '{"Args":["query","b"]}'
```

This is the full error text from peer0 org1:

```
2018-01-26 17:04:00.046 UTC [msp] GetLocalMSP -> DEBU 001 Returning existing local MSP
2018-01-26 17:04:00.046 UTC [msp] GetDefaultSigningIdentity -> DEBU 002 Obtaining default signing identity
2018-01-26 17:04:00.052 UTC [chaincodeCmd] checkChaincodeCmdParams -> INFO 003 Using default escc
2018-01-26 17:04:00.052 UTC [chaincodeCmd] checkChaincodeCmdParams -> INFO 004 Using default vscc
2018-01-26 17:04:00.052 UTC [chaincodeCmd] getChaincodeSpec -> DEBU 005 java chaincode disabled
2018-01-26 17:04:00.052 UTC [msp/identity] Sign -> DEBU 006 Sign: plaintext: 0AAA070A6608031A0B0880BFADD30510...696E766F6B650A01620A01610A023130 
2018-01-26 17:04:00.052 UTC [msp/identity] Sign -> DEBU 007 Sign: digest: 20D7EB048A7E3F59A74A3F7C1757E7CCCFFBFD2F5D5FC8A4BFF949051F22F99E 
2018-01-26 17:04:00.094 UTC [msp/identity] Sign -> DEBU 008 Sign: plaintext: 0AAA070A6608031A0B0880BFADD30510...21ED65F3952B1FE09A8E14D906B69E7C 
2018-01-26 17:04:00.094 UTC [msp/identity] Sign -> DEBU 009 Sign: digest: 285F91523D88D5D88CFCF7CDA89E6C81025D58116F2F33C1BE59DAEB9AA304D6 
Error: Error sending transaction invoke: got unexpected status: NOT_FOUND -- channel does not exist - version:1 response:<status:200 message:"OK" > payload:"\n &\2175\217\025\227\216Q\373a\020G\010\022{\3179\352\243\352\006\\\254\265\013\336\3070\002\237\353\315\022Y\nE\022\024\n\004lscc\022\014\n\n\n\004mycc\022\002\010\003\022-\n\004mycc\022%\n\007\n\001a\022\002\010\005\n\007\n\001b\022\002\010\005\032\007\n\001a\032\00295\032\010\n\001b\032\003205\032\003\010\310\001\"\013\022\004mycc\032\0031.0" endorsement:<endorser:"\n\007Org1MSP\022\226\006-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----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\ndGQS8yRG2kpOv1HKH0k=\n-----END CERTIFICATE-----\n" signature:"0E\002!\000\340\347\345\036\356\020\352\216\200\037\220$rk\320\243\025\006p\315\376\340C\\YG\030P\341\022i\262\002 \031\357M\2274\t\263\263\313\002=\206\224\321\255\r!\355e\363\225+\037\340\232\216\024\331\006\266\236|" > 
Usage:
    peer chaincode invoke [flags]

Flags:
    -C, --channelID string   The channel on which this command should be executed (default "testchainid")
    -c, --ctor string        Constructor message for the chaincode in JSON format (default "{}")
    -n, --name string        Name of the chaincode

Global Flags:
        --cafile string              Path to file containing PEM-encoded trusted certificate(s) for the ordering endpoint
        --logging-level string       Default logging level and overrides, see core.yaml for full syntax
    -o, --orderer string             Ordering service endpoint
        --test.coverprofile string   Done (default "coverage.cov")
        --tls                        Use TLS when communicating with the orderer endpoint
        --transient string           Transient map of arguments in JSON encoding
    -v, --version                    Display current version of fabric peer server
```

This is the full error text from peer0 org2:

```
2018-01-26 17:05:22.201 UTC [msp] GetLocalMSP -> DEBU 001 Returning existing local MSP
2018-01-26 17:05:22.201 UTC [msp] GetDefaultSigningIdentity -> DEBU 002 Obtaining default signing identity
2018-01-26 17:05:22.205 UTC [chaincodeCmd] checkChaincodeCmdParams -> INFO 003 Using default escc
2018-01-26 17:05:22.206 UTC [chaincodeCmd] checkChaincodeCmdParams -> INFO 004 Using default vscc
2018-01-26 17:05:22.206 UTC [chaincodeCmd] getChaincodeSpec -> DEBU 005 java chaincode disabled
2018-01-26 17:05:22.206 UTC [msp/identity] Sign -> DEBU 006 Sign: plaintext: 0AA6070A6608031A0B08D2BFADD30510...06696E766F6B650A01620A01610A0135 
2018-01-26 17:05:22.206 UTC [msp/identity] Sign -> DEBU 007 Sign: digest: 26976CF7AC5443DB2390C53818E2C4B64A7278DBB874101FD4B335189333294A 
2018-01-26 17:05:22.267 UTC [msp/identity] Sign -> DEBU 008 Sign: plaintext: 0AA6070A6608031A0B08D2BFADD30510...CC920EBFDA7DA672DC8EA94465B459B2 
2018-01-26 17:05:22.267 UTC [msp/identity] Sign -> DEBU 009 Sign: digest: B6965F71B9DBCC7CB4788BF260A477275C4FFB9393D8176FCBAD75333F566055 
Error: Error sending transaction invoke: got unexpected status: NOT_FOUND -- channel does not exist - version:1 response:<status:200 message:"OK" > payload:"\n \271\353p\303\250\000m\366dy\021(!\2043\002\305>]&u_\364o\250\335\305\026\3310\354T\022Y\nE\022\024\n\004lscc\022\014\n\n\n\004mycc\022\002\010\003\022-\n\004mycc\022%\n\007\n\001a\022\002\010\005\n\007\n\001b\022\002\010\005\032\007\n\001a\032\00290\032\010\n\001b\032\003210\032\003\010\310\001\"\013\022\004mycc\032\0031.0" endorsement:<endorser:"\n\007Org2MSP\022\226\006-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----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\nUVAM4j/ydnSQsfyfRA==\n-----END CERTIFICATE-----\n" signature:"0E\002!\000\240q\3370\307Iwi\036\022\305\035}!E\234\220\213\336`o\323\344\375\311\211j\361\t\343p\023\002 \177\026\351\234s\216\276=\207(\325\223i\264\303)\314\222\016\277\332}\246r\334\216\251De\264Y\262" > 
Usage:
    peer chaincode invoke [flags]

Flags:
    -C, --channelID string   The channel on which this command should be executed (default "testchainid")
    -c, --ctor string        Constructor message for the chaincode in JSON format (default "{}")
    -n, --name string        Name of the chaincode

Global Flags:
    --cafile string              Path to file containing PEM-encoded trusted certificate(s) for the ordering endpoint
    --logging-level string       Default logging level and overrides, see core.yaml for full syntax
-o, --orderer string             Ordering service endpoint
    --test.coverprofile string   Done (default "coverage.cov")
    --tls                        Use TLS when communicating with the orderer endpoint
    --transient string           Transient map of arguments in JSON encoding
-v, --version                    Display current version of fabric peer server
```

Comment: You will need to also mount an external volume for the orderer container as well

Comment: Hi, Gari!  Thank you for your help!  It works perfectly.

Comment: Just to be clear to other reading this question.  It will work after adding the following to volumes sections in docker-compose-base.yaml for orderer container data persistence as mentioned by Gari:
for orderer:
        - ../persist-data/orderer:/var/hyperledger/production

Answer (score 2):

By following Gari Singh's help, I have added the following line in the volumes sections in docker-compose-base.yaml for orderer container data persistence and the problem is solved.

```
for orderer:
    - ../persist-data/orderer:/var/hyperledger/production
```